# Run a command from cmd prompt and capture data in text file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, command-prompt

I am trying to run the below command from command prompt using vbscript and then capture the result in a text file.

**netstat -an -p tcp | find /c ":80" > C:\Users\Swarnabha\Desktop\test.txt**

I have written the below code but it is not working... Help me here plz!

```
Dim filepath
filepath= "C:\Users\Swarnabha\Desktop\test.txt"


Dim connstr
Dim portno

portno = ":80"
connstr = "cmd netstat -an -p tcp | find /c "& portno &" > "& filepath

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run connstr

Set oShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is edit the connstr to include the /c switch which carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates. You need to do that since you are specifying the > redirect command which "is a feature of the shell" to quote Bill Stewart.

```
connstr = "cmd.exe /c netstat -an -p tcp | find /c "& chr(34) & portno & chr(34) & " > " & filepath
```

You also need to put your port number variable in quote. 34 is the ANSI code for double quotes. That way your command will look like the following

```
cmd.exe /c netstat -an -p tcp | find /c ":80" > "C:\Users\Swarnabha\Desktop\test.txt"
```

I would consider as well grouping all your variable declarations as it is a good coding practice. You should also quote your `filepath` as that is likely to contain spaces at some point as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Matt but no data is being captured in the test.txt file when I am running the script... :(

Also FYI, my aim here is to capture the **count of ":80"** connections in the text file.

Comment: I didnt get any return either on your command in my text file. Just try the portion before the pipe `netstat -an -p tcp` to confirm the text file is populating. Do you get output on screen when you run your commnand?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. you need to encapsulate your variable in quotes so the command executes properly.

Comment: Forgive my error. I always referred to this which is what caused the mistake http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You're probably using [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) or similar.